# Beamer: Grouping environment counters

Tags: beamer, numbering, theorems

In *beamer*, when I use `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]` but this groups them all as the following.

[image: What I have]

What I want is *theorems*, *lemmas* and other environments to have different counters such as the following.

[image: What I want]

Is there a simple way for this? I can use *notheorems* option for *beamer* and redefine the environments myself but in this case the colour styles of the environments are removed.

Comment: You can say `\newtheorem{mylemma}{Lemma}` or `\newtheorem{mylemma}{\translate{Lemma}}` if you want to rely on multilingual features. The appearance of the `mylemma` environment will be the same as for theorems, but with autonomous numbering. This said, I prefer consecutive numbering even for presentations.

Comment: This also kills the colouring for `example`.

Comment: Please, give an example of what you're doing

Comment: Please see the pictures in OP (just added).

Comment: And where's the problem? The usual color for examples is green; you have to change some option for getting a different color.

Comment: When I apply your answer, the *green example* turns out to be a *blue example*. There is no way to keep it same?

Comment: Can you please give me a reference on how I can colour the new example as the old one?

Comment: @bkarpuz Use `\theoremstyle` according to my changed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`beamer` uses `amsthm`, which doesn't have a `\renewtheorem` like `ntheorem` does. You could hack into `beamer` (the file is `/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty`) but that is really *bad* behaviour. It's probably easier, to just `\undef` (from the package `etoolbox`) the macro `\lemma` and recreate the theorem with `\newtheorem`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma}{Foobar}
Foo and bar.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}{Barfoo}
Either bar or foo.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}{Something new}
No, not really.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Concerning other theorem environments: look at the above file. After `\mode<all>{` you'll find the definitions, `beamer` does, which you can `\undef` and recreate as you like. By default, the counting depends on the counting of `theorem` (except for `proof`/`beweis` of course). You'll also find the theoremstyles used for the different theorems. `example` for example (no pun intended) uses `\theoremstyle{example}`.

Comment: Nope, I do the same for `example` and it removes the `example` colouring. It is **not** *green* any more...

Comment: I changed the answer to accomodate for that.